# Writing a floating value in a stringstream and keep "." even if there is no decimal

Tags: c++, stringstream

I want to convert a `double element` in a string at a given `precision`. I want to avoid getting unnecessary `0` in my string (so I can't use [std::fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/)). Also, I want to always keep the "." in my string.

So I wrote the following function:

```
std::string toString(double element, int precision)
{
   std::stringstream stream;

   stream << std::setprecision(precision) << element;
   return stream.str();
}

toString(1.25, 2)  --> "1.25" OK
toString(1.25, 17) --> "1.25" OK
```

But now, imagine I do `toString(1., 2)`, then it returns to me `"1"`, but I want to keep the "`.`", so I want `"1."`

Do you have an effective way to do this?

PS: I'm not in C++11.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: search the string for a `.`, if there is none, append it to the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a trailing '.' in all cases, without also getting a trailing zero, you will need to do it yourself. However appending a '.' to a `std::string` since you have one anyway is fairly simple (its harder if you want to just work with streams only).

Also be aware of any locale specific issues (e.g. with the different uses of '.' and ',') if you ever need to support those.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::setprecision(precision) << element;
std::string str = stream.str();
if (str.find('.') == std::string::npos)
    str.push_back('.');
return str;
```

Alternatively, you could strip trailing zeros.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you for your reply. Finally I came up with something like that, and used [modf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/) hoping it's time effective